# Azure Entra Proxy images load on Edge but not Chrome Authentication Issue

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, authentication, entra-id, browser

I've noticed an odd issue that occurs only on Chrome, but not on Edge.

We have a web app server (IIS) and an image server. Both are accessed externally by users via an Azure Entra Proxy service.

-if the user accesses the page via Chrome through the proxy, the images DO NOT load unless the user first navigates to the image server to trigger a login on that server
-if the user accesses the page via Edge through the proxy, the images load
-if the user accesses the page via the internal network (not through the proxy service) on Chrome, the images load
-if the user accesses the page via the internal network (not through the proxy service) on Edge, the images load

Has anyone encountered this before? It seems like possibly some sort of authentication but. I was originally thinking it might be a CORS problem but I don't see any CORS errors (and that should presumably happen regardless of browser). I don't see why it works on Edge but not on Chrome. In all cases it's using Azure AD DS authentication.